# Using Selenium, Webdriver in a separate function in python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver, pynput

Pyhton 3.8,  Selenium 3.1.4.0,  pynput 1.6.8

I have a selenium project I'm working on, and it works fine when in one file, but it's getting pretty big 300~ lines.

I want to separate my project into a main file, and a functions file.

I know how to do this normally, but when using selenium I am at a bit of a loss, since you use driver.[various things] all over everywhere.

I am wondering if there is a good way to make it so my main can see the driver and use it, and my functions file can also see and use driver.

I have also included pynput because I am thinking maybe the with open statement that gets keyboard presses ( using the escape key to exit the project) is messing with things. I do not really understand joining threads and sending info to the queue, but that is for another post. This one is getting my driver to work over multiple files.

Also I know my function names are a mess, I'll get around to learning the proper naming conventions at some point.

The loading(listener) is a workaround for until I understand fully how multithreading works.

In my main file I have:

```
import functions as f

def main_Sequence(user_1, listen):
f.loading(listen)
f.sign_in(user_1)
f.loading(listen)
f.accept_Cookies()
f.loading(listen)
driver.refresh()

with keyboard.Listener(on_release=f.on_release) as listener:
    driver = start_Webdriver()
    main_Sequence(user, listener)
```

In my functions file I have functions  like this:

```
def on_release(key):  # TODO FIX Garbage listener BS
    if key == pynput.keyboard.Key.esc:
        return False

def accept_Cookies():
Cookies_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(., "OK")]')
Cookies_box.click()
return

def start_Webdriver():
    # Using chrome, and maximize browser for fewer issues
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    d = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    # Open the website
    d.get("URL.com")
    return d
```

I am wondering how to properly implement this.

The error I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "*ProjectFolder*/main.py", line 117, in <module> main_Sequence(user, listener)

File "*ProjectFolder*/main.py", line 87, in main_Sequence f.sign_in(user_1)

File "*ProjectFolder*\functions.py", line 117, in sign_in 

alert_Button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath").click()

NameError: name 'driver' is not defined
```

I have tried everything I could think of, I put it off as long as I did because my initials attempts proved unsuccessful.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `NameError: name 'driver' is not defined`. Send the `driver` instance, as parameter, to your methods which use `driver`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a singleton pattern, to get the driver object where ever you want it.
It would look something like this:

```
class WebDriver:
    __instance__ = None

    def __init__(self):
        if WebDriver.__instance__ is not None:
            raise RuntimeError("Cannot init class twice, as it is as singelton")
        else:
            WebDriver.__instance__ = start_Webdriver()

    @classmethod
    def get_instance(cls):
        """
        :rtype: WebDriver
        """
        if cls.__instance__ is None:
            WebDriver()
        return cls.__instance__
```

And your code would look like this:

```
# main.py
with keyboard.Listener(on_release=f.on_release) as listener:
    driver = WebDriver.get_instance()
    main_Sequence(user, listener)


# function.py
def accept_Cookies():
    driver = WebDriver.get_instance()
    Cookies_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(., "OK")]')
    Cookies_box.click()
    return
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I think it works, I just needed to change the line cls.__instance__ = Data_Presenter() or else it would not grab that the instance was changed, maybe that's not how you're supposed to do it but it works like a charm. just change that line and I will make it the accepted answer.

Comment: Arh, my mistake. I tried it out and called it DataPresenter. Forgot to change everything to webdriver. I've changed it now, to what I intended to do

Comment: I mean like this, if not it just keeps on making new instances.
in get_instance, in the `if cls.__instance__ is None:` instead of simply `WebDriver()` I need to put `cls.__instance__ = WebDriver()`

I still do not know if this is the best way but it's what's currently working for me.